# por que el service en angular no reconoce las tildes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

Hola amigos solicito de su colaboracion ya que tengo un servicio api el cual me retorna un listado en el cual los nombres contienen tildes de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
[
{
    "Id": "10",
    "Descripcion": "Equipo Prepago"
},
{
    "Id": "11",
    "Descripcion": "Equipo Pospago"
},
{
    "Id": "13",
    "Descripcion": "Recargas"
},
{
    "Id": "18",
    "Descripcion": "Tecnología"
},
{
    "Id": "21",
    "Descripcion": "Terminales"
}
```

]

El tema que tengo es que cuando realizo el llamado desde angular para llenar el listado me esta llegando de una manera diferente ya que lo que hace es que corrompe las letras que tienen tilde:
Asi tengo el llamado al servicio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ObtenerTiposVentas(cabData:consultaTipoVenta):Observable<consultaTipoVentaResponse>{
return this.http
.post<consultaTipoVentaResponse>(`${environment.API_URL}${environment.ApiConsultaTipoVentas}`, cabData,{headers: this.login.getHeader()})
.pipe(      
  map((res:consultaTipoVentaResponse) => {
    debugger;
    if(res == null){
      alert('La Respuesta de SAP no obtuvo resultados por favor verifique');
    }
    return res;
  }),
  catchError((err) => this.handleError(err))
)
```

}

y la respuesta que estoyu obteniendo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver me cambia la tilde por un simbolo diferente no se si alguno le haya pasado, estoy ultilizando angular 10 y necesito solucionar esta incidencia.

Comment: Por favor agrega un ejemplo de como te llega toda la información, no solo una imagen.

Comment: Por favor también Agrega el código como texto no como imágenes. De esa forma es mucho más fácil ayudarte

Comment: Hice la edicion, sin embargo la respuesta de la ultima foto es la que recibo desde el service de angular y es tal cual como te la envio en la pantalla.

Comment: puedes hacer un `console.log(res)`. Copia la respuesta por favor

Answer (score 0):

Bueno esta parte viene dada por temas de seguridad pues pueden existir temas de seguridad por ejemplo ataques de [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Algunos valores suelen estar prohibidos `<>/\,...etc`.

Bueno una forma de solucionarla es solicitar que estos datos lleguen encriptados y tu los desencriptas donde necesitas usarlos.

```js
//suponiendo que estas usando express como back solicitarias que esa data te llegue así
let encriptado = encodeURIComponent("testíon");
console.log(encriptado);
//donde la necesites la desenciptarias con:
let desencriptado = decodeURIComponent(encriptado);
console.log(desencriptado);
```

Por otro lado también es dado por problemas de acentos Español, Frances, Etc.
En ese caso te recomiendo leer la respuesta en [StackOverflow en Ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript) la cual tiene una explicación muy buena